# Событие для всех полей ввода, радиобаттонов и чекбоксов

Tags: angularjs, javascript

В `$scope` есть функция `putdata()`, которая отправляет на сервер данные. Данные нужно отправлять при событии `blur` с каждого поля (будь то радиобаттон, текстария и т.д.). Есть ли в angularJs возможность не писать каждому полю `ng-blur="putdata()"`, а, например, в контроллере прописать какую-то хитрость? Просто полей реально очень много, и мне кажется писать это в каждом поле будет неправильно по правилу DRY (Don't repeat yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете передать в контроллер параметр $element (Это будет тот тег, на который повешен контроллер), а дальше каким либо образом найти в нем все нужные вам элементы и навесить на них событие. Если на проекте используется jQuery то все очень просто, внутри контроллера:

```
$element.find('input, textarea, select').on('blur', function() {
    $scope.putdata();
});
```

Если же jQuery у вас нет, то все чуть сложнее. Как минимум придется написать 3 такие функции отдельно для каждого вида елементов:

```
$element.find('input').on('blur', function() {
    $scope.putdata();
});
$element.find('textarea').on('blur', function() {
    $scope.putdata();
});
$element.find('select').on('blur', function() {
    $scope.putdata();
});
```

так как сам ангуляр не умеет в селекторы и может искать только по именам тегов.